# React native selectable prop not working in iOS

Tags: react-native

Adding “selectable” prop in React Native Text component, I am able to select individual words in android simulator but in iOS simulator it selects entire Text content. How do I fix this?

Testing this on real devices also resulted in same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.